# AIX: what does the output from lscfg mean?

Tags: aix, hardware

I run lscfg:

```
lscfg -l  hdisk0
```

which returns:

```
  hdisk0           U787F.001.DPM5MVH-P1-T10-L3-L0  16 Bit LVD SCSI Disk Drive (73400 MB)
```

Question is: does someone know what these codes mean?

- U787F?
- 001?
- DPM5MVH?
- P1?
- T10?
- L3?
- L0 ... probably means lun0, right?

Does someone know the correct syntax for other devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have what's likely a Power5 type system (787F), model 001, serial number DP-M5MVH. I'd guess it was in the family: 9111-285, 9407-515, 9405-520, 9406-520, 9111-520, 9406-525, or 9131-52A. hdisk0 has a *logical* location code that translates as: the first (system) planar (P1), 10th port (T10), path 3 (L3), lun 0 (L0). The [corresponding physical location code](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/POWER5/iphau_p5/iphauresolving.pdf) is P3-D4, which you'd have to map against your actual system; if I was to guess, it'd be the top disk in the front of the unit.

[image: Front view of a sample IBM system, showing the physical location codes]

Other types of devices get other logical location codes mapped into the VPD; for more information, see the hardware references for your model(s) and the references below.

References:

- [Decoding location codes](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aix-decoding-location-codes/index.html)
- [AIX location codes](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/POWER5/ipha6_p5/aixloccodes.htm)